# Calculus Optimisation Problem - Computing Power

Tags: calculus

A researcher has funds to buy enough computing power to number-crunch a problem in 7 years if she buys now. However, computing power per dollar doubles every 20 months.

(a) When should she buy her computers to have finished the problem as soon as possible?
Give your answer as a decimal in months, accurate within 0.1 months.

(b) Suppose the problem would take *c* months on current computers. What is the largest value of *c* for which she should buy the computers immediately?
Give an answer as a decimal accurate to 0.1 months.

Help for just producing any kind of formula to help solve these questions would be SO appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You must have tried something.  Can you, say, determine the function $F(t)$ which represents the amount of time the calculation will take if you start at time $t$?  (So, measuring time in months, we have $F(0)=12\times 7,F(20)=6\times 7$ and so on).

Comment: @lulu I've tried that but unfortunately it's hard to figure out what to do with the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You clearly should not start before the computation takes $40$ months because you can wait $20$ months, start then with computers twice as fast and finish at the same time.

If you buy computers after $t$ months the power is $2^{\frac t{20}}$ times higher than today, so the computation takes $\frac {84}7{2^{\frac t{20}}}$ months.  She is then done at month $t+\frac {84}{2^{\frac t{20}}}$.  If nothing else you can just compute this for various values of $t$.  A spreadsheet will make it easy with copy down.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm still having a hard time as to what I'm looking for in questions (a) and (b). Any clue to what I'm trying to find?

Comment: I gave you the month she is done.  You need to find the $t$ that minimizes the expression.  You can do that by taking the derivative and setting to zero or by just listing it for various $t$ values.  I corrected the $7$ to $84$ because we are measuring in months.  For b the $84$ is replaced by $c$ so you need an analytic solution.  Do you understand the logic behind my expression?

Comment: I've managed to find (a) with your help but for (b), I don't know what to do after replacing _c_. I substituted _t_ = 0 as she should buy the computer immediately but this didn't help.

Comment: Substitute in $c$ for $84$.  Then you want to find the greatest $c$ so that the derivative of the completion time is positive at $t=0$ because that corresponds to being done as soon as possible by buying the computers now.